# findViewById returns null

Tags: java, android

I have simple code

```
package com.zim32;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView textvew = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logtext);
    }

}
```

textView is null. Why?
Here is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/logtext"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I found somethind about onFinishInflate. Where should i use it?

Comment: Is the name of your xml file Main.xml?

Comment: Is that xml file really main.xml?

Comment: Ye. It is main.xml On my emulator textview is rendered. There is no errors

Comment: It works on your emulator but not your phone?  Can you past the full logcat stack trace?

Comment: Strange. Just restart emulator and all goes fine.. Bug?

Comment: Have you tried project > clean? Sometimes Android just confuses its resources.

Comment: what do you do with your `textview` after declaring it? also is there actually a string in your `strings.xml` called `hello` that has a value?

Comment: @zim32 As I understand from your comment, it's working for you now. If you found a solution to a reproducible problem, please post it as an answer. If the problem cannot be reproduced it, then there is no question and it this should be closed.